# fetching data inside map in sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm having problems regarding fetching data inside a map function in sagas.

I want to initialize my posts onLoad through sagas.

I'm dispatching an action that has a generator function like this:

```
export function* initPosts() {
  try {
    //get categories
    const categories = yield call(fetchAll);

    //fetch 6 posts per category
    const posts = yield all(
      categories.map((category, index) => {
        const { _id, name, slug } = category;
        //insert posts in array of category
        const postArr = call(fetchByCategory, { id: _id, skip: 0, limit: 6 });
        return { name, _id, slug, index, posts: postArr };
      })
    );

    //dispatch payload to success
    yield put(fetchInitPostSuccess(posts));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchInitPostFailure(error.message));
  }
}

export function* watcherFetchInitPosts() {
  yield takeLatest(PostActionTypes.POST_FETCH_INIT_START, initPosts);
}
```

on success, i put the payload in state.

when i check the logger, everything looks good except the postsArr.

In the logger the payload shows that the posts array contain the following:

```
index: 1
name: "Category 3"
slug: "category-3"
_id: "5f2952d394e59b3c34605f64"
posts:
@@redux-saga/IO: true
combinator: false
payload: {context: null, args: Array(1), fn: ƒ}
type: "CALL"
__proto__: Object
```

But when i dispatch an action that calls only the fetchByCategory, its payload is correct. like here:

```
export function* fetchPostsByCategory({ payload }) {
  try {
    const posts = yield call(fetchByCategory, payload);
    yield put(fetchPostByCategorySuccess(posts));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchPostByCategoryFailure(error.message));
  }
}

export function* watcherFetchPostsByCategory() {
  yield takeLatest(
    PostActionTypes.POST_FETCH_BY_CATEGORY_START,
    fetchPostsByCategory
  );
}
```

How do i go about this.

UPDATE ****
I changed my code to the following just to see if the call on fetchByCategory works:

```
export function* initPosts() {
  try {
    //get categories
    const categories = yield call(fetchAll);

    //fetch 6 posts per category
    const posts = yield all(
      categories.map((category, index) => {
        const { _id, name, slug } = category;
        return call(fetchByCategory, { id: _id, skip: 0, limit: 6 });      
      })
    );

    //dispatch payload to success
    yield put(fetchInitPostSuccess(posts));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchInitPostFailure(error.message));
  }
}
```

It works but i want to also store the category name, id, slug with the postArray

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'm afraid of its performance

```
export function* initPosts() {
  try {
    //get categories
    const categories = yield call(fetchAll);

    const fetchedPosts = yield all(
      categories.map((category, index) => {
        const { _id, name, slug } = category;
        return call(fetchByCategory, { id: _id, skip: 0, limit: 6 });
      })
    );

    const mergedCatAndPost = categories.map((category, cIndex) => {
      const getPost = fetchedPosts[cIndex];
      const { _id, name, slug } = category;
      return { name, _id, slug, posts: getPost };
    });

    //dispatch payload to success
    yield put(fetchInitPostSuccess(mergedCatAndPost));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchInitPostFailure(error.message));
  }
}
```

Comment: Just thinking of creating a new route for init in my nodeJS to reduce my API Calls